# Test apache configure

Tags: apache, bash, output, configure

I'm working on a script to automatically install apache.
Before asking, this is a company request, otherwise I would use easier method to install apache.
Now, after the apache configure/make/make install I need to test for a successful completion. 
I checked the configure options but there is no flag for an unsuccessful finish.
I would like to know if there is any other way than to test the command output for a successful or unsuccessful ending?
Right now, I'm saving the output on a file and then grepping for an expected line. For example "creating test/Makefile" for the configure.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, on *nix based systems, commands return a 0 value for success and non zero value 
if the command was unsuccessful. In the shell, the exit status of the last command 
gets stored in the "$?" variable.

So, lets say you run your make install and check the exit status like so:

```
# make install 
# echo $?
```

If the command was successful, the echo statement will print out a 0, otherwise 
you will get some other numerical value. Alternatively you can then test the contents if the $? with "if".

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then { 
    echo "OK" 
};else { 
    echo "Not Ok"
};fi
```

You can also use the exit status in a different way. The following command line 
will execute each command, in order ONLY if the preceding command was successful

```
./configure && make && make install && echo "All good!"
```

Think of each COMMAND as a FUNCTION that returns a VALUE (its exit status)

&& is the AND operator for bash (The shell you are probably using.)  and || is the OR operator.

You can extend the above command line to also handle the case where the "make install" step fails, for example:

```
./configure && make && make install && echo "All good!" || echo "Something's awry"
```

Of course, this is just an example, but I think that you can solve your problem by taking advantage of the fact that you can test the exit status of commands.

This link should help you: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: The script has been working correctly for 6 months. Last night a member of my team tested it on a new server and it failed. But I think its one of those cases it was destined to fail.
Anyway, thank you very much, this give me some room to improve it :)